# How SQL OR operator is evaluated

Tags: sql, query-optimization, sql-server-2008-r2

System is: SQL Server 2008-R2

I have a table that one of its column is a tinyint named "Level".
Level is a non-negative number.

When I do:

```
SELECT XXXXX
FROM   YYYYY
WHERE ( ------------ ) AND 
      (Level >= @MinLevel) AND
      ( ------------ )
```

I get a correct response.

In an attempt to optimize the query, I tried to do:

```
SELECT XXXXX
FROM   YYYYY
WHERE ( ------------ ) AND 
      ((@MinLevel = 0) OR (Level >= @MinLevel)) AND
      ( ------------ )
```

If the requested minimum level is 0 there is no need to add the minimum 
level limitation to the query and by that save a comparison operator for the operation (assuming there is no index on Level)

What I got is actually a longer query or at least not a shorter query than the "un-optimized" one.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` Does that make any difference? Also is `@MinLevel` a local variable or a parameter?

Comment: Probably because you tried to take the job of optimizing the query from the dbms and did it yourself. The dbms knows better in most cases.

Comment: What do you mean by longer/shorter query? Longer execution time or a more complex [execution plan](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/query_execution_plan_analysis_p1.aspx)? I guess both queries should take about the same ammount of time when `@MinLevel = 0` because they have to return a larger dataset, and a simple comparison like that is normally very fast and could go  pretty much unnoticed. BTW, the kind of optimization you need is to [index your `Level` column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is sql-server-2008-r2, so we won't consider other DBMS.

Have a look here for some in depth analysis: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

It discusses many ways to perform dynamic searching which is somewhat relevant to the question. Particularly this quote:

> The effect of all the @x IS NULL
>   clauses is that if that input
>   parameter is NULL, then that
>   AND-condition is always true. **Thus,
>   the only conditions that are in effect
>   are those where the search parameter
>   has a non-NULL value.**
>
> .... And performance? **Very good
>   as long as you include the query hint
>   OPTION (RECOMPILE).**

This is found in the section `Static SQL` and **applies to** `SQL 2008 R2 CU1 (10.50.1702) or later`.

The same optimization shortcut (evaluate RHS only when `(@MinLevel = 0)`) applies to your query with the OPTION(RECOMPILE) hint.

<sub>(noticed that this has been suggested in comment against the question)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The OR clause isn't optimised (in almost any DBMS).
For example, it means an index will be ignored and both cases have to be evaluaTED

A straight >= is just a straight comparison

Answer (score 0):

The OR operative usually throws indexing out the window.

Imagine you have a table with an indexed id column that counts up once per row. In this table you have 100 rows. Row 1 would have a value 1 in this column, and row 100 would have a value of 100.

Now run this query:
**SELECT * FROM table WHERE column >= 45**

This query has a definitive start point: 45

So the first record it will check is right smack in the middle of your table, which the column value is 50. This is too high for 45, but it has eliminated half of the table that it doesn't have to look at. It will then look at the record in the middle of this group, which value is 25. This is too low, but again it has eliminated half of the results.

Long story short, in order to find the first 45, it has to look at only 6 to 7 rows. It then gives you every row from there to the end of the table as your result set.

Now lets tweak that query to be this: **SELECT * FROM table WHERE column >= 45 OR column = 43**

We no longer have a definitive start point. The database cannot determine one specific row to start your results from. In order to determine which records to return, it has to examine **every** row to make sure that it matches your requirement. If it matches, it adds this row to its results and moves to the next one.

Comment: I understand your case but in my case I compare to an SP parameter (@MinLevel) and not to a value in the database.